# Override aws-for-fluent-bit helm chart default input Mem_Buf_Limit value

Tags: amazon-web-services, charts, kubernetes-helm, fluent-bit

How do I increase the current default Mem_Buf_Limit for an INPUT?

When using helm charts, these are the aws-for-fluent-bit [default values](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/aws/aws-for-fluent-bit?modal=values&path=input.memBufLimit).

I have tried using the `extraInputs` in an attempt to change the existing value  in a separate yaml file but it does not work.

```
extraInputs: |
 Mem_Buf_Limit   10MB
```

I have also tried:

```
input.Mem_Buf_Limit:            10MB
```

is there a proper way to override the default values used by aws-for-fluent-bit helm chart?

Answer (score 0):

Following will provide the values that you can customize

```
$ helm show values <chart-name>
```

Then,
Pass the ".yaml" with your customisations using '--values' flag.

```
helm upgrade --install fluent-bit fluent/fluent-bit --values fluent-bit-config.yaml
```